# Insert text and add it to a named range for later retrieval

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, null, typeerror, google-docs

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script for Documents that will insert some text, and then add inserted text to a named ranged. To make sure that the inserted text is saved to a named range, I just want to select the inserted text.

Here's the code:

```js
function insertText() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docUi = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
    var insert = cursor.insertText('{insertedtext}');
    var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
    if (insert) {
      rangeBuilder.addElement(insert);
    } else {
      docUi.alert('Cannot insert text here.');
    }
  } else {
    docUi.alert('Cannot find a cursor.');
  }
  var savedInsert = rangeBuilder.build()
  doc.addNamedRange('myInsertedText', savedInsert)
  doc.setSelection(doc.getNamedRangeById('myInsertedText').getRange());
}
```

When I run the script, `doc.setSelection(doc.getNamedRangeById('myInsertedText').getRange());` generates the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to save the document before trying to access the new range.

Comment: , or run `.getActiveDocument()` again?

Comment: @SandyGood Those did not work.

Comment: I think there is a problem with `getNamedRangeById(id)` because `doc.setSelection(doc.getNamedRanges()[0].getRange());` works and `doc.getNamedRanges()[0].getName()` returns `myInsertedText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'myInsertedText'` is actually the namedRange's name, not the id:

```
  var namedRange = doc.addNamedRange('myInsertedText', savedInsert);
  var namedRangeId = namedRange.getId();
  doc.setSelection(doc.getNamedRangeById(namedRangeId).getRange());
```